# Kendo Tabstrip prevent duplicate tabs from opening

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, kendo-ui

I have a tabstrip which loads a page from URLContent.

I'd like to accomplish the following:

- If a tab with the targetted URL is already open, instead of appending a new tab, select the existing tab.
- If it's a new tab, append the tab dynamically and load it.

From the documentation, there seems to be no default way of handling this.

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/tabstrip

Also, I'd like to know if there are any ways to dynamically retrieve the ID/Name of the tab given it's tab index.

Here's how I'm initializing the Tabstrip:

```
<div class="mainContentTabStrip" style="width:100%;height:100%">
    <kendo:tabStrip name="mainVerticalTabStrip">
        <kendo:tabStrip-animation>
            <kendo:tabStrip-animation-open effects="fadeIn" />
        </kendo:tabStrip-animation>
    </kendo:tabStrip>       
</div>
```

And then to append a new tab:

```
function mainContentTreeView_onSelect(e) 
{
    var dataItem = $("#mainVerticalMenu").data("kendoTreeView").dataItem(e.node);

    var selectedNodeText = dataItem.text;
    var selectedNodeValue = dataItem.id;

    var mainVerticalTabStrip = $("#mainVerticalTabStrip").data("kendoTabStrip");
    mainVerticalTabStrip.append({
        text: selectedNodeText + 
            "  <img src='image/image/button_cancel.png' " + 
            "id='" + this.text(e.node) + "' " + 
            "name='" + this.text(e.node) + "' " + 
            "onclick='javascript:mainContentTreeView_delete()' " + 
            "onmouseover=" + this.text(e.node) + ".src='image/image/button_cancel_over.png' " +
            "onmouseout=" + this.text(e.node) + ".src='image/image/button_cancel.png' " +
            ">",
        encoded: false,
        contentUrl: "screen/" + selectedNodeValue,
        selected: true
    });
}
```

Comment: You can do it but you need to do it programmatically. How do you initialize the tabstrip using a DataSource or HTML `<li>`?

Comment: @OnaBai DataSource, from JSON string.

Comment: Would be possible to show it in the question or in a JSFiddle?

Comment: @OnaBai Actually, I was using the JSP wrapper ver to initialize it. I have edited the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some programming... there is not such functionality out-of-the-box.

What I propose is keeping an associative array where key save the `id` of the tabstrips (or the `url` if you prefer) and as value the index of the tabstrip that opens that `url`.

When `onSelect` is fired in the tree, you check if we have that tab already created if so we just select it. If it is not created we add a new element to the associative array and `append` a new item to the tabstrip.

In the following implementation I have opted for saving as `data` associated to the HTML element that represents the TabStrip.

```
function mainContentTreeView_onSelect(e) {
    var mainTreeView = $("#mainVerticalMenu").data("kendoTreeView");
    var mainVerticalTabStrip = $("#mainVerticalTabStrip").data("kendoTabStrip");

    var dataItem = mainTreeView.dataItem(e.node);
    var selectedNodeText = dataItem.text;
    var selectedNodeValue = dataItem.id;

    var data = mainVerticalTabStrip.element.data("my-data") || [];
    if (!data[selectedNodeText]) {
        mainVerticalTabStrip.append({
            text: selectedNodeText +
                    "  <img src='image/image/button_cancel.png' " +
                    "id='" + this.text(e.node) + "' " +
                    "name='" + this.text(e.node) + "' " +
                    "onclick='javascript:mainContentTreeView_delete()' " +
                    "onmouseover=" + this.text(e.node) + ".src='image/image/button_cancel_over.png' " +
                    "onmouseout=" + this.text(e.node) + ".src='image/image/button_cancel.png' " +
                    ">",
            encoded: false,
            contentUrl: "screen/" + selectedNodeValue
        });
        data[selectedNodeText] = Object.keys(data).length + 1;
        mainVerticalTabStrip.element.data("my-data", data);
    }
    mainVerticalTabStrip.select(data[selectedNodeText] - 1);
}
```

Running example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/czPFs/

**EDIT**: Since `Object.index` seems [not be supported in IE8](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/#Object.keys), here a different implementation not using it:

```
function mainContentTreeView_onSelect(e) {
    var mainTreeView = $("#mainVerticalMenu").data("kendoTreeView");
    var mainVerticalTabStrip = $("#mainVerticalTabStrip").data("kendoTabStrip");

    var dataItem = mainTreeView.dataItem(e.node);
    var selectedNodeText = dataItem.text;
    var selectedNodeValue = dataItem.id;

    var data = mainVerticalTabStrip.element.data("my-data") || { items: 0 };
    if (!data[selectedNodeText]) {
        mainVerticalTabStrip.append({
            text: selectedNodeText +
                    "  <img src='image/image/button_cancel.png' " +
                    "id='" + this.text(e.node) + "' " +
                    "name='" + this.text(e.node) + "' " +
                    "onclick='javascript:mainContentTreeView_delete()' " +
                    "onmouseover=" + this.text(e.node) + ".src='image/image/button_cancel_over.png' " +
                    "onmouseout=" + this.text(e.node) + ".src='image/image/button_cancel.png' " +
                    ">",
            encoded: false,
            contentUrl: "screen/" + selectedNodeValue
        });
        data[selectedNodeText] = ++data.items;
        mainVerticalTabStrip.element.data("my-data", data);
    }
    mainVerticalTabStrip.select(data[selectedNodeText] - 1);
}
```

Comment: I just checked the ECMAScript 5 Standards and it seems like Object.keys is not supported for IE8. Do you have any suggestions on the workaround for this?

Comment: Also, check **EDIT** for an alternative solution.